# Kotlin divide the list into lists

Tags: kotlin

I have list of objects and in object I have parametr productId and I want to for one big list get few list group by productId 
I try do this :

```
   val listOne = arrayListOf<TicketDisplay>()
                val listTwo = arrayListOf<TicketDisplay>()
                ticketDisplayList.forEach { ticket ->
                    when (ticket.zoneId) {
                        1.toLong() -> {
                            listOne.add(ticket)
                        }
                        3.toLong() -> {
                            listTwo.add(ticket)

                        }
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it using `groupBy`:

```kotlin
val groups = ticketDisplayList.groupBy { ticket -> ticket.zoneId }
// The list of the tickets with zoneId 1.
val listOne = groups[1]
// The list of the tickets with zoneId 3.
val listTwo = groups[3]
```

Comment: Thank you for help And Vould you  tell me can I mut this map to new Activity ?

Comment: @kikiKala2 what do you mean with "mut" ?

Comment: *put I try intent.putExtra("tickets_map",groups ) but I can not do this

Comment: @kikiKala2 The answer to your question isn't immediate since you have several choices. You can use a serialization library for example, or you can serialize it into a json and pass a string, or you can create a `Parcelable` wrapper.

Comment: I can not do this